# Flag -" other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" should not be available when already moderator has taken some action for question

Tags: support, flags, moderation, moderators

I have just noticed that one Question is marked as "Off-topic" by some moderators and when I click on "Flag" for same question then it shows me 3 options :

1 - It is spam

2 - it is offensive, abusive, or hate speech

3 - Other - Needs moderator attention

I agreed with options 1 & 2 , but why it is allowing to select option 3? because moderator attention is taken already for same question.

Comment: moderators aren't perfect, they could have missed something.. or something new could have came up, like an edit war that needs to be resolved, etc

Comment: @Sompuperoo - okay..

Comment: Although to be fair, there *are* people out there who for whatever reason will flag questions for moderator attention to ask for something that *has already been done by a moderator*. For example, guess what someone recently flagged a question that was closed four years ago as off-topic.

Comment: @Sompuperoo: No, guess what flag message they wrote.

Comment: @Sompuperoo -I understand that moderator not perfect. But if multiple moderator do any action for x question then it must be perfect. All could not be wrong. so at that time no need of that attention flag.

Answer (score 11):

There are several reasons that a post might need to be flagged more than once for moderator attention:

- There might be something else wrong that needs moderator attention (sometimes we handle a flag and move on, not noticing that there are other issues).
- The post might have changed after the first moderator action in a way that requires a second look.
- We might have made a mistake the first time. It happens.

In any case, the "Other" option is the last one I'd want to see disabled. That's the only one where users can type in a custom message and explain exactly why we need to look at a post again. That certainly gets abused often enough, but it's very often critical information that we would have missed otherwise.